# Tables breaking jQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

Why is that in IE 7/8 HTML tables break the jQuery UI accordion? I'm using a vanilla accordion with a couple of standard properties. It works great in Fire Fox and Chrome. Leaving jQuery's demo content is fine in IE 7/8, but as soon as you attempt to add a table and breaks.

Here is the [example](http://www.huntersatterwhite.com/xcelproducts/products/adhesives).

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap the `<table>` in a `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and it still breaks in IE7/8